# What are extended regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl

I am studying for an exam and one of the topics is on RegEx. There is a modifier, `x`, with the description 'uses extended regular expressions,' but it doesn't explain what this means. I can't really find anything on Google that fits the context of my study material.

On a quiz, one of the questions asked what modifier allows the use of comments in RegEx, and the correct(?) answer was `x`.

Could someone please help me make sense of this? Thank you.

Edit: I meant `x` in the context of `[gix],` where `x` is described as 'uses extended regular expressions.'

Comment: You almost certainly mean `/x`, not `\x`

Comment: I don't even know why I wrote `\x` to begin with, as in the study material it's written as `[gix]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented in [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)  (Just search for `/x`):

> Long regexps like this may impress your friends, but can be hard to decipher. In complex situations like this, the `//x` modifier for a match is invaluable. It allows one to put nearly arbitrary whitespace and comments into a regexp without affecting their meaning. Using it, we can rewrite our 'extended' regexp in the more pleasing form
>
> ```
>     /^
>           [+-]?         # first, match an optional sign
>           (             # then match integers or f.p. mantissas:
>                \d+\.\d+  # mantissa of the form a.b
>               |\d+\.     # mantissa of the form a.
>               |\.\d+     # mantissa of the form .b
>               |\d+       # integer of the form a
>           )
>           ([eE][+-]?\d+)?  # finally, optionally match an exponent
>       $/x;
> ```

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#x) documentation:

> `/x` tells the regular expression parser to ignore most whitespace that is neither backslashed nor within a character class. You can use this to break up your regular expression into (slightly) more readable parts...

The modifier improves readability, and allows us to add explanatory comments.

```
 /^            # the beginning of the string
   (?:         # group, but do not capture:
       foo     #   match 'foo'
      |        #  OR
       bar     #   match 'bar'
   )           # end of grouping
  $            # the end of the string
 /x;
```

Even without the `/x` modifier you can enclose comments.

```
/foo(?# match foo)/
```

Answer (score 2):

/x  to ignore whitespace that is neither backslashed nor within a character class. to make your regex more readable

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing two different concepts here.

The `/x` option to the match (`m//`) and substitution (`s///`) operators in Perl tells the regex parse to ignore white space. This is used to make your regex more readable.

[Extended patterns](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) are additions to the Perl regex engine so that it supports things (like look-ahead and look-behind) that aren't usually supported in regex tools.

Comment: Oh I agree completely. At least I passed the exam :p